# Web Service can't find SubSonic namespaces

Tags: c#, subsonic, synchronize

I installed WebService in another computer,and I have tried to browse my WebService, it always come with Compiler Error,it cannot find all SubSonic's classes.

**Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyTableController' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

What should I do?

Comment: Did you build the web service first? There's nothing special about web services that would cause that error. If you get the error in a web service, then you would have got it in a "normal" piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Are your web service built on your computer normally? if yes make sure that sunsonic dll is in web services bin directory